# debounced function 'not a function' in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, lodash, enzyme

I am trying to mock debounce so that I can test a debounced function in my unit tests but it is telling me the function `is not a function`

Error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _usersDialog.debounceUpdateSearchText) is not a function
```

Function:

```
export const debounceUpdateSearchText = debounce(
  (updateText, searchString) => {
    if (searchString === '' || searchString.length === 1) {
      updateText(' ');
    }
    updateText(searchString);
  },
  500
);
```

test code:

```
// earlier in the file
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
jest.mock('lodash/debounce');
// test
it('updates the search text', () => {
      // jest.useFakeTimers();
      debounce.mockImplementation(fn => fn);
      const updateText = jest.fn();
      // call function
      debounceUpdateSearchText(updateText, 'fuego');

      // jest.advanceTimersByTime(501);
      expect(props.updateText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fuego');
    });
```

Comment: if you exported your non-debounced function, you wouldn't have to mock anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my debounce mock was off by just a touch, working code:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => jest.fn(fn => fn));
```

Comment: thanks man, saved me from a headache. Btw, for vitest, use: vi.mock('lodash/debounce', () => ({ default: vi.fn(fn => fn) }));